# Divs will not float when wordpress theme is activated online - fine on localhost

Tags: css, wordpress, localhost, wordpress-theming

I have a theme that involves a main area and sidebar on the index page, and two equal columns on inside pages that contain individual posts.

When viewed on a local host, the columns float perfectly, and they won't float at all once the theme is activated online. I've tried a number of solutions including applying box-sizing:border box to various classes, changing the display: properties fiddling with the size of certain elements, and so on, but it refuses to work.

the site is at http://shanepeacock.ca/

I'm looking for a fix for the elements that need to float, but I'd also like to figure out how to set up my localhost environment so it actually shows me what I'm going to get once I upload the theme. Wordpress is up to date in both places.

Answer (score 1):

Use `box-sizing: border-box` to account for padding:

```
.sidebar {
padding: 10px;
margin: 1%;
width: 33.75%;
float: right;
box-sizing: border-box; /* ADDED */
}

.blog-container {
padding: 10px;
width: 62.25%;
margin: 1%;
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box; /* ADDED*/
}
```

`border-box` tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an element's width and height. If you set an element's width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any border or padding you added, and the content box will shrink to absorb that extra width. This typically makes it much easier to size elements. [More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: Ok, that works. It seems like the problem was that I expected those divs to inherit box-sizing from their parent elements, so I can probably remove that property from those that don't actually float themselves